How to make searchbox larger in ReactJs?
the issue I am facing so far is that I could not make the searchbox in the navbar larger; I noticed the searchbox is not increasing in size or the logo in the navbar is turning slimmer.
Please find code below:


import React from 'react'
import logo from '../Assets/sampa.png'
import * as Fas from 'react-icons/fa'
/*import * as Delivery from 'react-icons/ci'*/
/*import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'*/
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../Home/Home.css'

const Home = () => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>
        <section className='navbar-container'>
            <div className='navbar_left'>
                 <div className='logo'>
                            <img src={logo} alt=''/>
                   </div>
                   <div className='searchbox'>
                             <input type='text' placeholder='Search for products...'/>
                             <i><Fas.FaSearch/></i>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div className='navbar_right'>
                  <div className='cart'>
                           <i><Fas.FaShoppingCart/></i>  
                           <span>Cart</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className='delivery'>
                           <i><Fas.FaBox/></i>
                           <span>Delivery</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className='login'>
                           <button type='submit' onClick={() => navigate('Signin')}>SignIn</button>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
.navbar-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #2c143e;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.navbar_left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar_right{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}

.searchbox{
    width: 200%;
    padding-left: 300px;
    
}


input{
    border: 3px solid purple;
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.searchbox i{
    position: relative;
    left: 12rem;
    top: -2.3rem;
    color: #2c143e;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.cart{
    position: relative;
    left: -10rem;
}

.cart i{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.cart span{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: -0.5rem;
}


.delivery{
    position: relative;
    left: -7rem;
}

.delivery i{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5.5px;
}

.delivery span{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: -0.9rem;
    padding: -5px;
}

.login{
    position: relative;
    left: -4rem;
}

/*
.login button{
    background-color:#febd69;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
   /* box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #febd69;
    cursor: pointer; 
}*/



I need to know how to make it larger without affecting the size of the logo; please find evidence of the issue in the screenshot attached in this question.  Thank you for your support.

I can't check this code now... but you have input with static width - 500px
try use flex: 500px 1 1 for wrapper for input and width: 100% for input...
and you already have flex wrapper inside .navbar-container
what I recomend you:

fix wrapper sizes for .navbar_left, .navbar_right
use gap for spaces inside flexbox (remove padding-left: 300px for .searchbox)
try rewrite width for flex-base for flexbox items
if you need static width for your logo use flex: 100px 0 0 on logo wrapper and width: 100% for logo

